# TemplateSyntaxError NoReverseMatch when adding a page to Django-page-cms

Tags: django

I have just installed Django Page CMS, which looks quite promising for a certain problem i have right now. After reading through the docs at packages.python.org, and doing the described settings, i got it to appear in the admin interface. But as soon as i try to add a page, i get that error message:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/pages/page/

Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'pages-details-by-path' with arguments '(u'faq',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

As i assume this has something to do with my url configuration, here is the lines that include the django page cms urls:

```
urlpatterns+= patterns('',
    (r'', include('pages.urls')),
)
```

I have not worked too much with reverse url lookups yet, and page cms is completely new to me, so i would be glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

**edit:**
Stupid - i have got a seperate dev_url.py for development. Have been working for two weeks on the production server and just forgot about it. The code above works perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

The URL pattern you included is matching everything- including admin, which I don't believe you're supposed to.  According to the django-page-cms [docs](http://packages.python.org/django-page-cms/installation.html#urls) `urls.py` should look like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^pages/', include('pages.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: If i specify the admin urls before the pages urls, all of the admin urls are filtered and not even going to the pages app. This is the same pattern as the catchall flatpages pattern.

Comment: The pages app admin pages should be within the existing admin, matched by `(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`.  There is an admin folder within the django-page-cms app that will be included in your admin page as long as you have `admin.autodiscover()` in your urls.py.

Comment: The code you provide just specifies the pages urls first, then the admin urls. I don't know what you mean by "within the existing admin" - is there anything special about that? All models and apps appear within the standard admin pages, as soon as they have an admin class. admin.autodiscover is on, code still does not work.

Comment: I guess I don't know what you mean by _all of the admin urls are filtered and not even going to the pages app_.  To my knowledge (although I've never used django-pages-cms) the only admin pages that django-pages-cms uses are those discovered by the built-in admin, accessible through `(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`.  What admin pages are you trying to get to, that you're not able to?

Comment: Of course you'd need to make sure that `'pages'` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in order to see the pages admin section within your admin.

Comment: By all of the admin urls are filtered i mean: first i specify the `r'/admin/'` admin-urls, then the catch all `r''` for the pages url. When Django is passed a url now, the url parser first(!) looks for any url matching the `r'/admin/'` regex, and passes all matching urls to admin. A url matching the `r'/admin/'`will not even get to the point in program where my later specified `r''` - catchall pattern is being evaluated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The behavior that you're describing is exactly what is supposed to be happening. `/admin/` should only be handled by admin. Why do you want it being passed to the `pages` app? The `pages` admin section will be within `/admin/` because its admin has been auto-discovered.

Comment: Unless you mean that you want to create a page called 'admin' that should be matched by the `pages` app? In which case its url would be `/pages/admin/`

Comment: If you don't want to use the `admin` namespace for the django-admin, you could change it to `django-admin` and have it before pages, then have pages be the catchall.